# Не могу понять почему не могу получить корректный json (XLSX JS)

Tags: javascript, json, xlsx

с PHP получаю XLSX файл в формате ArrayBufer,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

далее прогоняю через функцию с использованием библиотеки XLSX JS

```
    convertDataToWorkbook(worksheet){
       /* convert data to binary string */
       let dataSheet = new Uint8Array(worksheet);
       let arr = [];

       for (let i = 0; i !== dataSheet.length; ++i) {
        arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(dataSheet[i]);
       }
       let bstr = arr.join('');
       return xlsx.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });
    }
```

Результат этого - просто набор символов который не могу превратить в нормальный JSON с нормальными символами..
JSON.parse -нет
[image: uncorrect_Json]

Может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой...
По итогу я хочу забирать ключи и формировать массив с шапкой и строками для заполнения веб таблицы.

Comment: На скрине "набор символов" - это собвственно бинарный xlsx файл, без всякой обработки. Может как-то не так или не там обрабатываете?

Comment: в доке говорится _ArrayBuffer that can be viewed as an Uint8Array and fed to XLSX.read *using array* type_. Попробуйте `xlsx.read(data, {type:"array"})` https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/tree/5d18f826645842cda76f1eed784cce71fac982a2/demos/xhr#xmlhttprequest

Comment: Пожалуй соглашусь с некорректными данными которые приходят с PHP.
Я формирую new FormData()
let formData = new FormData();
let getIdInput = this.importModal.querySelector(`[name = "fileupload"]`);
formData.append("import", getIdInput.files[0],getIdInput.files[0].name);

И отправляю в php, там сохраняю в app/public сам файл xlsx и возвращаю
 return response()->json([
                        'data' => mb_convert_encoding(Storage::disk('local')->get($filename), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8'),
                        'error' => null
                    ], 200, [], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, получается что я получаю с php - xml формат со всеми описаниями Context и тому подобное и толкаю в обработку.
А тогда как нужно обработать его перед тем как толкать обратно в response ?